# How to concatenate columns using Computed Column in mysql

Tags: mysql

In my schema I had two columns ,I am new to MySQL how to concatenate columns using Computed Column in mysql

```
ordertbl schema

Autoorderid int  auto-increment
Orderid         varchar(45)
```

I want to insert the orderid value using Computed Column in mysql  by concatenate

**input**

```
orderid ="ord" +(Autoorderid )value
 example :orderid ="ord" +10002
```

**result**

```
orderid= ord10002
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use mysql [**CONCAT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function like

```
 UPDATE your_table set orderid = CONCAT("ord",Autoorderid);
```

Check here how to write

```
mysql> SELECT CONCAT("ord",10000);
+---------------------+
| CONCAT("ord",10000) |
+---------------------+
| ord10000            |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: 10000 every time it will add that but I want to CONCAT to auto increment value of Autoorderid that id should be uniqe

Comment: Can you give your expected output what actually you want with input and output data

Comment: orderid ="ord" +(Autoorderid )value
 example :orderid ="ord" +10002  check my edited question

Comment: I want this for when the new record is inserted at the same time orderid should also inserted

Comment: i had created trigger for this USE `ntc_sales`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `order_master_BINS` BEFORE INSERT ON `order_master` FOR EACH ROW
   SET NEW.OrderID =  CONCAT('ORD' ,NEW.AutoOrderID) ;
end; but this trigger is not working